# Finding which word is occurring in given sentence

Tags: string, algorithm

I've list of words. Number of words is around 1 million.

I've strings coming at runtime, I've to check which word from the list is present in string and return that word (need not to return all words occurring in sentence, returning first one also suffice the requirement).

One solution is checking all words one by one in string but it's inefficient.

Can someone please point out any efficient method of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) algorithm. Although a million words is not all that much. You can also convert your text body into a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) structure and then use that to check your search list against. There is a special kind of Trie called a [Suffix Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) used especially for full text searching.

Comment: +1, because this is the general approach for finding a substring, however note that you might need to do more work because you are not looking exactly for a substring, but for a word in... so for example if the set is `"abcd","efgh"` - and you encounter `"abcdefgh"` or `"bcd"` there should be no match. It can probably be done by adding a special character at the beginning and at the end of each word - both in the set and when matching.

Answer (score 0):

Put your word list in a tree or hash table.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your word's list is ordered (or inserted in a efficient data structure like an ordered binary tree) to perform a binary search, the solution you are proposing is the most efficient one.